# How to get the path of the selected item in QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I am using *QTreeView* and *QFileSystem* model:

```
QTreeView *treeview;
treeview = new QTreeView(win);
QFileSystemModel *fsm = new QFileSystemModel;   
fsm->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath()); 
treeview->setModel(fsm); 

......
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

```
QModelIndex index = treeview->currentIndex();
QString path;
if (index.isValid())
{
    path = fsm->filePath(index);
}
```